# How do I get my Median Program to work (part 2)

Tags: python, python-2.x

I am trying to make a median program. This is my code.

```
def median(list=[]):
    x = 0
    list = sorted(list)
    if len(list) % 2 == 0:
        b = int((len(list)/2))
        print b
        c = int(len(list)/2)
        x = [list[b-1],list[c]]
        print x
        x = float((x[0]+x[1])/2)
        print str(x)
    else:
        print list[((len(list)//2))]
```

When I run it, I get this

```
>>> median([1,2,3,4])
2
[2, 3]
2.0
```

What is happening?

Please note: I do not want any advice on ways to do it better, I just want help.

Comment: Are you using Python 2?

Comment: I'm not sure. I use Pythonista. Does it matter?

Comment: I think Pythonista uses Python 2.7.4

Comment: Yes, it does. Please, show the result of `3 / 2`.

Comment: It returns 1 when 1 type 3 / 2

Comment: Thanks @soon I will try this

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.4 has  `statistics.median`

Here is a example of how to use it

```
import statistics

values = [1, 2, 3, 6, 8]

print(statistics.median(values))
```

If you don't use python version 3.4 you could always right a function like this one i have included

```
def median(lst):
    lst = sorted(lst)
    if len(lst) < 1:
            return None
    if len(lst) %2 == 1:
           return lst[((len(lst)+1)/2)-1]
    else:
            return float(sum(lst[(len(lst)/2)-1:(len(lst)/2)+1]))/2.0
```

while these may be the more pythonic way to do it, if you would like your specific function, you can do it like this

```
def median(list=[]):
    x = 0
    list = sorted(list)
    if len(list) % 2 == 0:
        b = int((len(list)/2.0))
        print b
         c = int(len(list)/2.0)
        x = [list[b-1],list[c]]
        print x
        x = float((x[0]+x[1])/2.0)
        print str(x)
    else:
        print list[((len(list)//2.0))]

median([1,2,3,4])
```

Comment: I want to write my own function. I am not asking for how to do it better, I am asking why I am getting this result

Comment: you need to make 2 a float in your func

Comment: i edited my post accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Try this, look for 2.0 instead of 2 on division

```
def median(list=[]):
    x = 0
    list = sorted(list)
    if len(list) % 2 == 0:
        b = int((len(list)/2.0))
        print b
        c = int(len(list)/2.0)
        x = [list[b-1],list[c]]
        print x
        x = float((x[0]+x[1])/2.0)
        print str(x)
    else:
        print list[((len(list)//2))]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should cast the elements of `x` to a float before taking the average:

```
def median(list=[]):
    x = 0
    list = sorted(list)
    if len(list) % 2 == 0:
        b = int(len(list)/2)
        print b
        c = int(len(list)/2)
        x = [list[b-1],list[c]]
        print x
        x = (float(x[0])+float(x[1]))/2
        print str(x)
    else:
        print list[((len(list)//2))]

median([1,2,3,4])
```

In the original you had `x = float((x[0]+x[1])/2)`. So that's adding 2 integers and dividing them. If this is python 2 the you run into the integer division problem (I don't believe this will happen in python 3 because `/` is float division by default). You fix this by explicitly telling python that your values are floats (as I did above), or you can `from __future__ import division` and just use the default float division from python 3.

Also, `b` and `c` are both set to the same value so you don't need to store them both separately. Just use either `b` or `c` when calculating your list `x`